# Syntax error when using setOnClickListener (Android)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener

I'm just starting out with Android and am working my way through a cookbook and trying out code. My problem is that every time I try to use setOnClickListener I get two syntax errors; one above where the code is going and another at the end of the class. I have copied the code out exactly from the book but am still getting the error. I have tried Google searching, but nobody else seems to have the same problem so I am either doing something wrong or there is a bug in Eclipse.

```
package com.example.tes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);


startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
}
});

}
```

The errors appear on lines 21 - "`Syntax error on token "}", delete this token`" and "`Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody`". There are no errors when I add only the "startButton.setOnClickListener" code and they only appear when I try to set the onClickListener.

I am sure I have made an error somewhere, but I honestly can't see it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: EDIT: I forgot to state the second error occurs on line 31, i.e. at the end of the code.

Comment: You forgot to put it in a method

Comment: Keyser means move your button initialisation and setOnClickListener into onCreate.

Comment: Looks like a perfectly valid "newbie" question so I've negated the (in my opinion) unfair downvote with an upvote.  Keeps the balance correct in the Androidverse you see.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting an error because your code is floating in the middle of nowhere, and isn't inside a method. Try using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trigger);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I misunderstood the code I was reading as the book did it step-by-step without showing the actualy complete code. Therefore I thought that I was creating an actual method, and didn't need to put it inside of another method.